# Why won't my xaml see my code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting the following error:

> The name MinMaxOverlay does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Shadow_App".

Here are my xaml and code-behind snippets. Please be warned that the code I use is much much longer, but I removed only the relevant portions. The error when all of the code (1000's of lines) is still the same.

```
<UserControl xmlns:igWPF="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml/wpf"  
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:local="http://schemas.AvalonControls/AvalonControlsLibrary/Controls"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             x:Class="Shadow_App.MainView"
             xmlns:myLocal="clr-namespace:Shadow_App"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="900" Width="1000" x:Name="window">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid Background="Black" Margin="0,50,-4,-1" Width ="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="847" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <myLocal:MinMaxOverlay/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

```csharp
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Bloomberglp.AppPortalApi;

namespace Shadow_App
{
    [BlpApplication]
    public partial class MainView : UserControl
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class ChartOverlay:UIElementCollection
    {
    }
    public class MinMaxOverlay : ChartOverlay
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to comment `<myLocal:MinMaxOverlay/>`, build your project and then uncomment it again. Worked for me...

Comment: That didn't work :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to clear all other errors out of my code (they were related to the reference not working), clean and then build the project with that  still in it. Damn to the depths whatever muttonhead thought of WPF!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a public constructor to your class will make it visible.